# Can't figure out the reason of this typescript error

Tags: typescript

For the below class and interface declaration:

```
import MixedInTrait from '...';

interface NodeConnection<
    TListeners extends any = any, 
    TBroadcasters extends any = any
> extends MixedInTrait {}
class NodeConnection<
    TListeners extends any = any, 
    TBroadcasters extends any = any
> { ... }

/** I need the interface to be named exactly like the class, so that the mixins, ie, adding a "Trait" to the class works correctly, and I get typing support for it. According to TypeScript documentation, if I name a class and an interface the same, they will be merged together **/
utils.applyMixins(NodeConnection, MixedInTrait);
```

I am getting the following typescript error:

```
class NodeConnection<TListeners extends unknown = any, TBroadcasters extends unknown = any>
interface NodeConnection<TListeners extends unknown = any, TBroadcasters extends unknown = any>
All declarations of 'NodeConnection' must have identical type parameters.ts(2428)
```

First of, why is typescript thinking that I am trying to extend `unknown` instead of the `any` type I written, and why does it think that the two type parameters are not identical? How should I solve this issue?

Comment: Why do you have an interface and a class with the same name, but also not even indicating that the class implements the interface? Do you need the interface at all?

Comment: @crashmstr the interface is to let TypeScript know about the mixin parameters that I am applying on the class, I just omited the `extends` part from the interface, for brevity

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `any`. Since `any` can accept any data type, typescript can't assure that the both declaration of NodeConnection would have same type. But, in case you have specific types as follow:

```js
interface NodeConnection<
    TListeners extends String, 
    TBroadcasters extends String
> {}
class NodeConnection<
    TListeners extends String, 
    TBroadcasters extends String
> {  }
```

In this case, typescript is assure that the base type would have atleast functionality of `String`. Due to which is allows it.

You can try this at: [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIHsAmEDC6QgQJjD4A8AUMtcgCoAywAzpIVE8hAB6uYcDKYKKADmAGmRUatAEJR0cTAjgtoHbrwFDRFAHzIA3gF8KCADYqOGbHgJES5KdQbNWazjwgg+yQcJDikjR0cgpKKpDsHpq+2gF6htRGQA)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to both declare an interface and to create a class with exactly that interface. You can simply just create the class and use it as an interface:

```js
class NodeConnection<
    TListeners extends any = any, 
    TBroadcasters extends any = any
> { ... }

class MyNodeConnection implements NodeConnection<MyListeners, MyBroadcasters> 
{
  ...
}
```

Note that using `implements` like this is different from using `extends`:

```js
class MyNodeConnection extends NodeConnection<MyListeners, MyBroadcasters> 
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: I need the interface, the way it is: please see the edit to the original question.